# Extract key value from a string Using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

There is a scenario in which I am sending an HTTP request and getting this response String from the server.

```
submitstatus: 0
smsid: 255242179159525376

         var streamResponse = newStreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().ToString();
```

I want to extract the key values by using LINQ. New to LINQ any suggestions.

Comment: can you post the streamResponse value?

Comment: @Rockstart stream response value is submitstatus: 0
smsid: 255242179159525376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using `output` string to simulate the result

```
string output = @"submitstatus: 0
smsid: 255242179159525376";

// you can use regex to match the key/value
// what comes before `:` will be the key and after the value
var matches = Regex.Matches(output, @"(?<Key>\w+):\s(?<Value>[^\n]+)");

// for each match, select the `Key` match as a Key for the dictionary and
// `Value` match as the value
var d = matches.OfType<Match>()
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Groups["Key"].Value, v => v.Groups["Value"].Value);
```

So you will have a `Dictionary<string, string>` with keys and values.

---

Using `Split` method

```
var keysValues = output.Split(new string[] { ":", "\r\n" },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < keysValues.Length; i += 2)
{
    d.Add(keysValues[i], keysValues[i + 1]);
}
```

---

Trying to use purely `Linq`

```
var keysValues = output.Split(new string[] { ":", "\r\n" },
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var keys = keysValues.Where((o, i) => (i & 1) == 0);
var values = keysValues.Where((o, i) => (i & 1) != 0);
var dictionary = keys.Zip(values, (k, v) => new { k, v })
                     .ToDictionary(o => o.k, o => o.v);
```

Comment: I was also thinking in the similar manner.  Dictionary<string, string> outputDictionary=  streamResponse.Split(':')[1]
.Select(x = > x)                                                    .ToDictionary(y => y[0], y => y[1]);   but not able to figure out What should be put in Select Statement....

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use regex? Smth like:

```
(?<=submitstatus:\s)\d+
```

for submitstatus
and

```
(?<=smsid:\s)\d+
```

for smsid